# aggregate columns with 2 data frames

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to aggregate multiple columns given certain conditions using R (data.table?)...
I have one data frame df1 with columns 12:262 that contains species abundance (each column) for each sample (rows)

```
sample species1  species2
sample1    1    21
sample2   47    36
sample3    8    32
```

In another data frame df2, I have the phylum, genus, etc.. for each species (rows) .

```
species phylum  genus
species1    X    A
species2    Y    B
```

I would like to aggregate all columns from df1 whose species belong to the same phylum (defined in df2)...
Does that make sense?

thank you!

Comment: Could you clarify what your final output would look like, based on your example? For instance, would you want for each `phylum` the total number/abundance across all species/samples? Also, you mention `data.table` with a question mark, and tagged as well - did you prefer a `data.table` solution?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to do is to reshape df1. If you convert the data from a 'wide' format to a 'long' format you will have multiple rows for each sample. You can then merge this with your second data set by the `species` variable. From here, you haven't given enough detail on exactly how you want to aggregate the data, but I provided two simple examples. You should be able to easily adjust that aggregation code to include whatever you need.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df1 <- data.frame(
  sample = c("sample1", "sample2", "sample3"),
  species1 = c(1, 47, 8),
  species2 = c(21, 36, 32))

df2 <- data.frame(
  species = c("species1", "species2"),
  phylum = c("X", "Y"),
  genus = c("A", "B")
)

df1_long <- tidyr::pivot_longer(df1, starts_with("species"),
                                names_to = "species", values_to = "abundance")

df3 <- dplyr::left_join(df1_long, df2, by = "species")

df3 %>% 
  group_by(phylum) %>% 
  summarize(total_abundance = sum(abundance), 
            avg_abundance = mean(abundance))
```

Answer (score 0):

A **data.table** version

```
library(data.table)
dt1 <- data.table(
  sample = c("sample1", "sample2", "sample3"),
  species1 = c(1, 47, 8),
  species2 = c(21, 36, 32))

dt2 <- data.table(
  species = c("species1", "species2"),
  phylum = c("X", "Y"),
  genus = c("A", "B")
)

# long format 
dt1_long <-
  melt(
    dt1,
    id.vars = 'sample',
    variable.name = "species",
    value.name = "abundence"
  )
# join and group
dt1_long[dt2,on = "species",by = "phylum"]
```